# How to calculate the target string in a UITextFieldDelegate method?

Tags: string, swift, range

**Problem**

In UITextFieldDelegate's `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` we are given the original text in `tf.text`, the replacement string, and the range.

This is sufficient information to calculate the target string (what the TextField would contain if we didn't intercept), but I'm having trouble getting this code to compile:

```
func textField(
  tf: UITextField,
  shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange,
  replacementString str: String
) -> Bool
{
  var tgt = String( tf.text )
  tgt.replaceRange( range.toRange(), with: str )   // PROBLEM HERE
  NSLog( "realtime: %@", tgt )
  return true
}
```

The problem I seem to be having is, String's `replaceRange:with:` takes a character, not a String.

*Perhaps there is a better or easier approach to calculate tgt?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you use `NSString`s methods. Change the first line of your method to declare an `NSMutableString` instead of a `String`:

```
func textField(tf: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, 
    replacementString str: String) -> Bool {
        var tgt = NSMutableString()
        tgt.appendString( tf.text )
        tgt.replaceCharactersInRange( range, withString: str )
        NSLog( "realtime: %@", tgt )
        return true
}
```

(The problem stems from `NSRange` and built-in Swift `Range` instances not being compatible for strings.)

Comment: this looks promising - xcode is giving me a problem with the instantiation of tgt though (NSString is not a subtype of NSMutableString)

Comment: Updated - this might be overkill